# How to limit the result count of NSFetchRequest?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I want to have a feature of "Recent 20 Items" in my iOS app. I use Core Data and `NSFetchRequest`. How can I limit the result number to 20 to achieve this? Thank you in advance!

Kai.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

set the [fetchLimit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001170-BAJBEABG) of the NSFetchRequest

```
[request setFetchLimit:20];
```

Comment: Only adhered to when underlying storage is SQL database

Comment: @NielsCastle I wonder how do you know this ? I was having some unpredictable results and your comment saved me. I couldn't find this information in the documentation.

Comment: @Petar So what to do to avoid ignoring this property?

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3.0 uses:

```
request.fetchLimit = 20
```